# FlowNet2.0 in Google Colab

Tags: python, c++, github, pytorch, google-colaboratory

Is it possible to run this FLowNet2.0 code in google colab? https://github.com/NVIDIA/flownet2-pytorch
This code relies on custom layers named 'Resample2d'. These layers are not written in python or pytorch but in c++. Can we run them in google colab?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I've been working with FlowNet2 on Colab for my Bachelor's thesis. You can find an already-set-up notebook [here](https://github.com/Gauravv97/flownet2-Colab/blob/master/Flownet2_Colab.ipynb).